# Does any one know the difference between CentOS 5.6 and CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos6, centos5

I am upgrading CentOS 5.6 to CentOS 6.4, can anyone give me the differentiating points or a link to a website that shows that

Comment: 0.8? More seriously, I don't think this is a good fit for SO, and I'm not sure if any other sites would welcome such a broad question.

Comment: http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS6.4

Comment: And have you tried to find anything?

Answer (score 0):

The entire release history is at http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes

You will need to read/combine the release notes for 5.7..5.10 & 6.0..6.4 and you may also need to take a look at the bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

It's a major upgrade from 5 to 6 so the list of differences is long and it's dedicated multiple webpages to the changes in doing that, just google "centos migrate 5 to 6" and you get a ton of hits.
Redhats planning guide at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/pdf/Migration_Planning_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-6-Migration_Planning_Guide-en-US.pdf is one that points out differences and what you need to plan for.